# Django REST Framework - OneToOne Relation through JSON

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I want to create an API that allows to send JSON through a POST request.
The JSON should then get passed on to a serializer which takes care of creating a new object and populate it with the existing data.

It works fine for the 'simple' cases such as basic character-only inputs like usernames and alike, but I am seriously stuck when it comes to creating a OneToOne relation. Here's the sample code.

Function called `employee_list` in `views.py` - `data['account']` is a valid username, a `User` instance is successfully being selected!

```
data = JSONParser().parse(request)
user_object = User.objects.get(username=data['account'])
data['account'] = user_object # this is now a valid User object 
serializer = EmployeeSerializer(data=data)
if serializer.is_valid():
  serializer.save()
  return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

The model

```
class Employee(models.Model)
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  name = models.CharField(...)
  surname = models.CharField...
  account = models.OneToOneField(User)
  role = ...
  salary = ...
  picture = ...
```

And the serializer

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Employee
    fields = (...) # all fields of the `Employee` model
```

So far so good, however, the serializer never validates! When I remove the need for a OneToOne relation, it works..

How can I create a new Employee objects with a working OneToOne relationship to a User object?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the validation error? You can pass raise_exception inside: is_valid(raise_exception=True)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, didn't even know this was possible. It gave me the exact error, I was able to solve it alone because of this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `pk` of the `User` object, rather than the `User` object.

**Solution**:

```
data['account'] = user_object.pk
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because a user object is being passed to the serializer, when it can be just passed to the serializer, while saving the object. Try something like this:

```
data = JSONParser().parse(request)
user_object = User.objects.get(username=data['account'])
serializer = EmployeeSerializer(data=data)

if serializer.is_valid():
  # pass object to save, instead of saving in the data dictionary
  serializer.save(account=user_object)
  return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)

return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Comment: Yep, tried that as well, then I saw that I can just use the primary key instead, this was way easier. Upvoted anyway, maybe this is helping others. ;)